# Extract a list from list of lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list of lists in java.

```
static ArrayList<List> permutationS = new ArrayList<List>();
```

The inner list is an ArrayList of integers.

```
List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now I want to select an innerList, If it contains a particular integer.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want every list that contains at least one instance of that integer?

Comment: @k.krol.27 there will be only one list containing a particular integer. Here is an example:[[0, 6, 13, 14], [1, 10, 11, 18], [2, 22, 4, 20], [3, -1, 21, 12], [5, 9, 17, 16], [7, 15, 19, 8]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> permutationS = new ArrayList<>();

// list initialization here

int i = 5; // the Integer you are searching for

for(List<Integer> innerList : permutationS) {
   if(innerList.contains(i)) {
     // found, do something with innerList
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to remove all of the `List<Integer>`s that do not contain a particular integer (10, for example):

```
permutationS.removeIf(list -> !list.contains(10));
```

---

Another solution would be to use streams and filtering to accomplish it:

```
permutationS.stream()
            .filter(list -> list.contains(10))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If you're only looking for a single `List<Integer>`, then you could use the following:

```
List<Integer> newList = permutationS.parallelStream()
                                    .filter(list -> list.contains(10))
                                    .findAny()
                                    .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

Comment: `parallelStream()` offers no advantages other than the possibility of faster execution when more cores are available. `parallelStream()` _doesn't always guarantee faster results_. In fact, A parallel stream has a much higher overhead compared to a sequential one. There are only certain cases in which you'd want to use `parallelStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

As of I do not know which Java version you are using I suggest looping throught it like

```
List<List<Integer>> Permutation_S = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); 
for(List<Integer> listInList: Permutation_S){
    for(Integer integerValue: listInList){
        if(integerValue == 2 /*your desired value*/){
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can use streams, if you are on Java 8 or higher

Comment: permutationS is of type List<List<?>> not List<List<Integer>>

Comment: so List<List<T extends Object>> ?

Comment: (actually worse as it uses the rawtype but it is considered the same as a wildcard type)   Type<?> is the same as Type<? extends Object> as everything extends Object, but T is not provided so T is out of the question... next to which iirc, its E instead of T

Comment: But he asked for Integer

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `stream`:

```
int x = 3; // the number to be looked

List<Integer> selectedInnerList = permutationS.stream()
                                              .filter(s -> s.contains(x))
                                              .findFirst()
                                              .get();
```

Note that `findFirst()` returns an Optional object, so `get()` will throw an exception if there is no such element

Comment: This will throw an exception if no list contains `x`

Comment: @JacobG. Edited my answer to clarify this

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares what is from where is s coming?

Comment: @sheldoncooper s is the parameter of the lambda (an anonymous function). We don't need to declare it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public List getList(Object value) {

    for (List inner : Permutation_S) {
        if (inner.contains(value))
            return inner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a structure like this ?

```
for (List<Integer> lists : permutationS) {
    for(Integer integers : lists){
        //Your tests 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to get the list which contains the value you want, and if no-one of the inner lists contains it, it will return a new empty list :

```
int val = 10;
List<Integer> innerList = permutationS.stream()    //iterate over inner lists
        .filter(list -> list.contains(val))        //keep one which contains the value
        .findAny()                                 //keep only one if exists
        .orElse(new ArrayList<>());                // if no-one return new List
```

---

*Example :*

```
permutationS.add(Arrays.asList(0, 6, 13, 14));
permutationS.add(Arrays.asList(1, 10, 11, 18, 6, 78, 79, 9));
permutationS.add(Arrays.asList(2, 22, 4, 20));

List<Integer> innerList = permutationS.stream().filter(list -> list.contains(10))
                                               .findAny().orElse(new ArrayList<>());
innerList.size(); // = 8

List<Integer> innerList2 = permutationS.stream().filter(list -> list.contains(34))
                                                .findAny().orElse(new ArrayList<>());
innnerList2.size(); // = 0
```